# События MouseDown и MouseUp для button в UI Toolkit Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Сразу обращу внимание, что кнопка создана не в Canvas, а через UI Builder.

Я по уроку разобрался как отловить Клик по кнопке:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class UIButtons : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Button delete;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var root = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;

        delete = root.Q<Button>("Delete");

        delete.clicked += Clicked;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Clicked()
    {
        Debug.Log("CLICKED");
    }
}
```

А как отловить события MouseDown и MouseUp для той же кнопки?

Comment: Не через кнопку, а [IPointerDownHandler и IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html).

Comment: Шикарно! Спасибо большое!
Только в документации написано вешать скрипт на GameObject, а у меня кнопка сверстана в UI Builder и изначально ее нет в сцене. Или я что-то не понимаю?